# Add recipients to message in concise way w/ Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three models (`Message`, `User`, and `Recipient`). I have a method on `Message` that currently looks like this:

```
def add_recipient(emails)
  emails.split(' ').map do |email|
    user = User.where(email: email).first_or_create
    user.persisted? ? user : nil
  end.compact.map do |user|
    recipient = Recipient.new(message: self, user: user)
    recipients << recipient
    recipient
  end
end
```

Basically it can take one or more emails (separated by a space), attempt to find or create a valid user w/ it (which stripping away any invalid emails), and then add them as a recipient to the message.

This works but I feel that it's VERY ugly. What can I do to refactor this method?

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring suggestions? OK, here we go!

1. Show intention: If you add multiple recipients, rename it to `add_recipients` (plural).
2. Single responsibility: Is it really a good idea to `find_or_create` users within this action? How are you going to report that an email was invalid?

   It is also not clear to the reader of the code why you are checking `persisted?` that would at least require some comment. Because of that I would handle this login elsewhere and simply pass a list of users to that method.
3. Use the association methods: You can call `build` or `create` on association proxies like `self.recipients.build`.

Writing all this, my code would look totally different:

```
users = User.where(email: emails.split(' '))
users.each { |user| message.recipients.build(user: user) }
```

Comment: The reason for first_or_create is that if this is the first time the user is attempting to send a message to a user and they aren't in our system we'll create a User record that they will then claim upon login.